# how to aggregate two columns using ag-grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm using ag-grid and angular2 for grid.

On 1st trial, I tried to make rowspan.

But ag-grid doesn't support rowspan. 
Instead ag-grid have a aggregation feature.

I'm stuck for aggregating two columns.

Here is my plan to display grid.

[image: Grid to display]

I hope that grid display 2nd title "Description" show "commcodes->desc" if it is aggregated, and show "commcodes->detailcodes->desc" if user expand it.

Here is my json data for displaying to grid and repos.
https://github.com/badsaarow/CommCodeViewer

```
{
    "commcodes": [
        {
            "commcode": "ACC", 
            "desc": "ACC is blabla...", 
            "detailcodes": [
                {
                    "desc": "AC is blabla", 
                    "detailcode": "AC"
                }, 
                {
                    "desc": "CR is blabla", 
                    "detailcode": "CR"
                }, 
                 ...
        {
            "commcode": "BCC", 
            "desc": "BCC is blabla...", 
            "detailcodes": [
                {
                    "desc": "TC is blabla", 
                    "detailcode": "TC"
                },
```

Is it possible with ag-grid?

Comment: Hi @sungyong, version 18 [now supports rowSpan](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-spanning/)

Comment: Thanks @TonyD,   I'll try it with news version as your advice.